# validation for DTOs and business objects

Tags: c#, dto

when using DTOs in client-server architecture you can have some validations on client side that checks the DTO objects. when the DTO is sent back to the server after it converts back to business objects it can be verified for some server side validations. so it seems that here some logical code duplication is exists, for validation of DTOs and business obejcts, how can I remove this code duplication??

Answer (score 1):

Put the validation and DTO code in a common project that is referenced by both the client and server projects.

Comment: but the validator can not work with both of the business object and DTO because they have different data types

Comment: Ok. Well one way to implement business objects is to have them inherit from the DTOs - that way you can reuse any code that works on the DTOs with the business logic. You can also factor out common validation code into new routines and call them, depending on your requirements. Good luck

Comment: but the DTOs can flatten business objects, so inheriting from them made business objects have some fields of other business objects, it seems it is not the way.

Comment: It all depends on how you design the system. 'the way' is whatever you design it to be.

Answer (score 1):

If you have simple validations like "This property is required", or "this int property must be in range x..y" you can use [Data Annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901590%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). These can be validated on client and server side with the [Validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class. Depending on your frontend, your View can use these as well for checking user inputs.

The `Validator.ValidateObject` method returns a list of validation results which give you error messages for every failed validation.

Comment: Just to clarify, ValidateObject() returns no value but only raises an exception for the first violation found. TryValidateObject() returns a Boolean indicating success or failure and also allows you to pass an ICollection object that will be filled with any validation failures.